# Stack trace : Attempted Invalid PurchFormLetter.main of Appeal running in CIL on the client

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I created a web service for the generation of a vendor invoice in the class which allows the call to this web service I called the Action type of menu item that allows you to call the `Purchformletter` class, however, an error is displayed in the SoapUI , the answer is:

> Monitoring the battery: Attempted invalid PurchFormLetter.main of
>   Appeal running in CIL on the client.

called to the menu item is:

```
args.record ( mytable) ;

menuFunction = new MenuFunction (' PurchFormLetter_Invoice :: Action ) ;
menuFunction.run ( args) ;
```

however if i use this code in job, it works

thanks in advance

Comment: Martin Dráb , any help please ?

Comment: I don't think martin visits here, by the way this isn't a personal support site where you can ask anybody anything in person

Answer (score 1):

You can not call *Controller* from the service. You shoud call the service class (`\Classes\FormletterService\postPurchaseOrderInvoice` in your example).

And for the *FormletterService* there is already standard AIF Service (`\Services\FormletterService`). Just create AIF port with `FormletterService.postPurchaseOrderInvoice` operation.

Comment: Create new [Inbound port](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202090.aspx) and expose [Service operation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202119.aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: Hi all,
I need help. I have to create an invoice using purchformletter according to a vendpackingslip without opening a form vendeditinvoice,cause i will execute my code in a wen service.
Have you any idea
Thanks in advance